# Incorrect Syntax near keyword 'Transaction' SQL Insertion Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't understand where the error is. I've done this a million times before, but for some reason, this error keeps coming up. Here are my Create Table Statements:

```
CREATE TABLE chf.Transaction
(
TransactionID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
AmtDue MONEY,
DiscountPercent DECIMAL(5,2),
AmtPaid MONEY,
Date DATETIME,
)
GO

CREATE TABLE chf.Agent
(
AgentID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(50),
TransactionID INT,
constraint Agent_T_FK foreign key (TransactionID) REFERENCES    chf.Transaction(TransactionID),
)
GO
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Transaction` is a keyword. So it is not allowing. If you want to use `Transaction` as table name then use like this.

`CREATE TABLE chf.[Transaction]`

But I strongly recommend **not to use the keywords / reserved words**

Answer (score 5):

Transaction is a reserved word. put [] around it like so

```
CREATE TABLE chf.[Transaction]
(
TransactionID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
AmtDue MONEY,
DiscountPercent DECIMAL(5,2),
AmtPaid MONEY,
Date DATETIME,
)
GO
```

Comment: I would add to this the same comment Ravindra had in his. You should not name tables reserved words. They have been reserved for a reason.

Answer (score 3):

It is happpening just because you are trying to use predefined keywords as table name. You should delimit it with [] symbol.

```
      CREATE TABLE [transaction]
      (

      );
```

**Find the all keywords list in this link-**
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507(v=sql.80).aspx